# How do I edit my bio?

Tags: support, editing, profile-page, user-profile

Two years ago I wrote that I was a freshman, but I have moved on since then. However, on both the mobile app and the full website I seem to be unable to edit my bio. Is it possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Click your name at the top of the page. Then select Profile.  Then you should have an "click here to edit"

Comment: Also, do that on the main site, not meta (the button is labeled "Edit profile & settings").

Answer (score 6):

Go to [your profile page on the main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current) (not on meta or it won't work), then click on [Edit Profile & Settings](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) in the navbar.

Comment: I updated this answer so that it works for any user who clicks on it, not just the OP.